scaling an image on top of another image in pygame
I'm new to pygame and relatively new to coding in general, so I'm sure some of my code is unnecessary or inefficient. I'm working on a lifebar, and I have a green bar on top of a red bar to show their health. The lifebars are scaled to the size of the screen and the red one scales correctly, but the green one stays how it was. The width of the bar is supposed to be based on the ratio, self.health_ratio,  between the current health and total health, and that's where the scaling messes up, however, I can't figure out how to fix it. Any other tips would also be greatly appreciated, ty <3
class Lifebars:
    def __init__ (self,rpg_game):
        """Initialize the lifebar and set its starting position"""
        self.screen = rpg_game.screen
        self.settings = rpg_game.settings
        self.screen_rect = rpg_game.screen

        #load lifebar image and get it's rect
        #green lifebar/ health
        self.lifebar_pos = pygame.image.load("images/lifebars/lifebar_full.bmp")
        self.lifebar_pos = pygame.transform.scale(self.lifebar_pos, (150,50))
        self.lifebar_pos_rect = self.lifebar_pos.get_rect()

        #red lifebar/damage
        self.lifebar_neg = pygame.image.load("images/lifebars/red_lifebar_full.bmp")
        self.lifebar_neg = pygame.transform.scale(self.lifebar_neg, (150,50))
        self.lifebar_neg_rect = self.lifebar_neg.get_rect()

        #times resized
        self.resized = 0

        #health ratio
        self.health_ratio = 1.0

    def _lifebar_check(self,health, max_health):
        self.health_ratio = health/max_health

    def on_resize(self, new_screen_rect, width_ratio, height_ratio):
        """When screen is resized, lifebar is resized too"""
        self.resized += 1

        self.screen_rect = new_screen_rect

        if self.resized % 2 == 0:
            self.lifebar_pos = pygame.transform.scale(self.lifebar_pos, (150,50))
            self.lifebar_pos_rect.x = int(self.lifebar_pos_rect.x * width_ratio)
            self.lifebar_pos_rect.y = int(self.lifebar_pos_rect.y * height_ratio)

            self.lifebar_neg = pygame.transform.scale(self.lifebar_neg, (150,50))
            self.lifebar_neg_rect.x = int(self.lifebar_neg_rect.x * width_ratio)
            self.lifebar_neg_rect.y = int(self.lifebar_neg_rect.y * height_ratio)
        else:
            self.lifebar_pos = pygame.transform.scale(self.lifebar_pos, (150 * width_ratio, 50 * height_ratio))
            self.lifebar_pos_rect.x = int(self.lifebar_pos_rect.x * width_ratio)
            self.lifebar_pos_rect.y = int(self.lifebar_pos_rect.y * height_ratio)

            self.lifebar_neg = pygame.transform.scale(self.lifebar_neg, (150 * width_ratio,50 * height_ratio))
            self.lifebar_neg_rect.x = int(self.lifebar_neg_rect.x * width_ratio)
            self.lifebar_neg_rect.y = int(self.lifebar_neg_rect.y * height_ratio)
            
    def blitme(self):
        """Draw the lifebar"""
        self.screen.blit(self.lifebar_neg,self.lifebar_neg_rect)

        #this is the part that messes it up
        self.lifebar_pos = pygame.transform.scale(self.lifebar_pos, (self.lifebar_pos_rect.width * self.health_ratio, self.lifebar_pos_rect.height))
        #end of part that messes it up
        
        self.screen.blit(self.lifebar_pos, self.lifebar_pos_rect)

